# Java PriorityQueue not polling expected object

Tags: java, priority-queue

This is my first post here so feel free to point me in the right direction regarding formulating a question here.

My issue is with the java.util.PriorityQueue.

I have a queue that I initialize;

```
    myComparable comp = new myComparable();

    PriorityQueue<someObject> prioritized = new PriorityQueue<someObject>(11, comp);
```

I dont think it matters for the question what is in my queue or how myComparable is implemented.

I then get unexpected output:

```
prioritizedObject = prioritized.poll();

for(someObject otherObject : prioritized)
{
    System.out.println(comp.compare(prioritizedObject, otherObject));
    System.out.println(comp.equals(prioritizedObject, otherObject));

}
```

For one object in the list this prints:
1
false

How can this be? How can I poll() an object from the queue while the comparator Im using says that another object in the queue is smaller?

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with the queue. It's your Comparable method that is not going the right way. You queue only gets all objects. There is only one, so that doesn't seem to be it. Have you done unit tests on your `myComparable` class?

Comment: It really is impossible to tell without seeing more code. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demostrates this?

Comment: "I dont think it matters for the question what is in my queue or how myComparable is implemented." -- How can you say this when you don't know why your code isn't working?  Truly amazing.

Comment: What I mean is, from my basic level of understanding, if my comparator returns 1 when comparing object A and object B then object B should always be polled before object A however my comparator is implemented? The comparison is right after the poll() so nothing could have changed here, right?

Comment: The comparator does nothing with the queue priority. It just compares your object A and B. So apparently, there are other objects in the queue as well with a higher prio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case everything else is right (no concurrent pushes, not getting the test wrong), I could imagine two reasons:

- the objects change in a way affecting their order (forbidden)
- the comparator is wrong (not transitive or whatever)

Comment: Based on the really short code sample you have here -- I'm guessing maartinus' second option is probably what's up -- post the comparator.

Comment: Yeah, Im sorry, I thought that if A < B then A would always be polled before B but I do have some ambiguity in the queue which I think allows for A < B, B < C, C < A which of course would allow for B to be polled before A. Thanks all!